# Как реализовать доступ к тяжеловесному объекту с кучей методов

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Подскажите, как реализовать доступ к **HeavyObjectWithManyMethods** в **Document**, избегая копирований, и, не реализовывая все методы **HeavyObjectWithManyMethods** в **Document**. 
Заранее спасибо.
Вот код, закончить который не могу:

```
class TreeStructure
{
public:
    /*
    Реализация древовидной структуры
    */
};

class HeavyObjectWithManyMethods
{
private:
    unsigned char _data[1024 * 1024 * 100]; //100 MB
public:
    /*
    Очень много методов
    */
};

class Content
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> _lines;
    TreeStructure _tree;
    HeavyObjectWithManyMethods _obj;
public:
    void addLine(const std::string &line) { _lines.push_back(line); }

    void eraseLine(unsigned id) { _lines.erase(_lines.begin() + id); }

    unsigned countLines() const { return _lines.size(); }

    std::string& operator[](unsigned id) { return _lines.at(id); }
    const std::string& operator[](unsigned id) const { return _lines.at(id); }
};

class Document
{
private:
    Content _content;
public:

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте геттер, возвращающий константную ссылку на тяжелый объект:

```
class Content{
    HeavyObjectWithManyMethods _obj;
public:
    const HeavyObjectWithManyMethods& obj() const{
        return _obj;
    }

    //Как заметил @Александр, можно еще добавить такую перегрузку
    HeavyObjectWithManyMethods& obj(){
        return _obj;
    }
};
```

Comment: Можно и не константную, чтоб вызывать не константные метод тоже

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте Content наследником HeavyObjectWithManyMethods, тем более он его содержит.